# Why does my Python distribution install each package in its own directory in site-packages?

Tags: python, pip, packaging, pypi

I created a distribution package called `myapi-1.0.0.tar.gz` that has two python packages inside it (api and helpers). When I `pip install` it in my virtual environment, it `api` and `helpers` python packages are installed into their own folder in the root site-packages, instead of all being installed in a `myapi` folder.

This is the file structure of my project:

```
myapi/
├── api
│   ├── api.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── dist
│   ├── myapi-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
│   └── myapi-1.0.0.tar.gz
├── helpers
│   ├── helper_1.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── __init__.py
├── pyproject.toml
├── setup.cfg
└── setup.py
```

After running `pip install myapi-1.0.0.0.tar.gz`, `pip list` shows that myapi version 1.0.0 is installed.

However in `.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages`, these folders are created:

```
myapi/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/api/*
myapi/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/helpers/*
myapi/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/myapi-1.0.0.dist-info/
```

For every package and sub package I have in my project, when installed as a distribution package with pip, they are installed into the root of `site-packages`.

How do I get my distribution package to install all the packages and files as they exist in my project under the folder 'myapi' in `site-packages`?

note that all __init__.py files and helper_1.py/api.py are empty.

setup.cfg:

```
[metadata]
name = myapi
version = 1.0.0

[options]
packages = find:
```

setup.py

```
import setuptools
setuptools.setup()
```

pyproject.toml

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

I have setup.py present in the project to allow me to create an editable installation, and pyproject.toml there to satisfy PEP standards, while most of the other configuration I try to put into setup.cfg

Answer (score 1):

Change your file structure to the following.

```
myapi/
├── myapi/
│   ├── api
│   │   ├── api.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── helpers
│   │   ├── helper_1.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── pyproject.toml
├── setup.cfg
└── setup.py
```

Comment: Can you explain why this is necessary?